# Countdown then redirect jquery

Tags: jquery, timer, hyperlink, countdown

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="http://google.com" class="red">
```

Basically once user click this, a lightbox will appear with a timer then goes the url using data-url. Is that possible?

---

How would you combine theses too,

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    link.onclick = function(){
       $('.lightbox').show();
        setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = link.getAttribute("data-url")}, 1000)
    }

});

$(function(){
  var count = 10;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
      window.location = 'http://google.com';
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible. You could try.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: $(function(){
  var count = 10;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
      window.location = 'http://google.com';
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
});

Answer (score 0):

Really trival simple example that should get you started.

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    link.onclick = function(){
        // make the modal popup here.
        alert("imma let you finish but first imma take you to a new webapge in 1 second");

        // after the setTimeout go to a new page
        setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = link.getAttribute("data-url")}, 1000)
    }
​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/QsKJF/)**

(Note live demo will not actually forward due to jsFiddle)

Comment: Nice! But how would I embed that into a inline html with a counter and put it on a lightbox?